# Кто убивает sleep PHP процессы в UBUNTU?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, sleep

У меня работает множество экземпляров PHP скриптов, запущенных в консольном режиме.
Скрпит делает некое действие, затем выполняется usleep (300000), затем цикл повторяется.

С недавнего времени по неизвестной причине некоторые процессы стали убиваться по неизвестным причинам. В strace сообщение
`+++ killed by SIGKILL +++`
. Действие происходит совершенно с любым процессом, запущенном в любом месте на сервере, т.е. сама по себе привязка к конкретной директории или пользователю не присутствует.
В логах syslog, dmesg, и вообще в любых других найти причину не удалось.
Есть подозрение, что когда одно из ядер процессора нагружается на 100% (такое периодически присутствует, но ядер 80 и на нагрузку это не влияет), какой то системный демон убивает случайные процессы, которые в этот момент (как правило в strace прослеживается) находятся в спящем состоянии.

Кто сталкивался с подобным? Где искать причину, как исправить?

Comment: А что с памятью? Может OOM?

Comment: @AlexeyTen memory_limit = -1 в cli режиме. На ООМ грешу, но логов нет, и вообще не пойму существует ли он в моей системе

Comment: оом в дмесге отмечается. а так наверное лимит по времени. если так хочется спать в пхп, то лучше после каждого цикла форкать новый процесс пхп